# Picture box not showing inside panel - Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

In my code when the form loads I am trying to create a picture box inside of the form. When the code that includes the picture box in the form is deleted the picture box appears just fine but when I add that code back in it no longer is viable.
Here is my code:

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim picAlien1 As New PictureBox
    Me.Controls.Add(picAlien1)
    picAlien1.Size = New Size(24, 16)
    picAlien1.Location = New Point(pnlRow1.Location.X, pnlRow1.Location.Y + 8)
    picAlien1.Image = Space_Invaders.My.Resources.Resources.alien_1_phase_1_pixilart
    pnlRow1.Controls.Add(picAlien1)
End Sub
```

Comment: A control can have only one Parent.  So calling Controls.Add() twice cannot work.

Comment: It looks like you want it to be at the same position as pnlRow1, but down slightly.  Get rid of the last line that adds it to pnlRow1, then make sure your PictureBox is in FRONT of the other control with `picAlien1.BringToFront()`?